# How to correctly format a "for" loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying to make a simple program with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 5;
int b = 0;

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a, i++)
    {
        b++;
    }
    
    printf("%i", b);
}
```

However, when I try to compile I get the errors: `relational comparison result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison]` and `expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier` for line 8. I've tried to look at several different sources on how to construct `for` loops and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < a, i++)` needs to be `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)`

Comment: Also, why the use of global variables here? `int a = 5;` and  `int b = 0;` should **both** be inside `main`. And, `main` should return an `int`, e.g. `return 0;` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example where you can practice interpreting the error statement. As you'll see, it says `expected ';' in 'for' statement specificer`. That's saying there's a place where you should have a semi-colon but you don't.

In your casse, there should be a semi-colon after the `i < a`. Right now, you have a comma.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough- I thought it was referring to the semicolon as in the end of a statement and I was tying myself in knots trying to figure out how to close the statement but obviously I was going down completely the wrong track. Thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using **`,`** instead of **`;`** in the for loop after the statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
```